# Does WMI read user information from windows credentials manager?

Tags: windows, wmi, credentials

I wanted to connect to a remote Windows cluster using WMI to read its node information. User credentials are stored in Windows Credentials Manager. But, WMI does not seem to read user credentials from Windows credentials manager.I tried with WMI Explorer tool and with the below code (C#). Any idea how to get it work?

```
{
    ConnectionOptions Options = new ConnectionOptions();
    //Options.Username = Username;
    //Options.Password = Password;
    Options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:";
    Scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\WindowsCluster\root\cimv2", Options);
    Scope.Connect();
}
```

I get access denied error if I do not pass username and password. I tried with all possible authentication modes including default and packet privacy.

Comment: Is there anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it does not use Windows Credential manager. You will need to fill out username and password when connecting remotely. Also, if you are connecting to that machine with a domain account then you will need to add the domain name after the colon in the authority field. Otherwise if its machine creds then don't define authority at all.

Hope this helps.